# i want a powershell script from which i extract few lines from csv file to another csv and calculate entire column time values

Tags: powershell

Here is my data in csv file

```
"Day","Person","Start","End","Elapsed"
"2022-10-01","108   ","22:34","22:35","00h, 01m, 25s"
"2022-10-04","108   ","08:44","08:46","00h, 02m, 01s"
"2022-10-10","108   ","14:13","18:19","04h, 06m, 52s"
"2022-10-11","108   ","09:38","09:42","00h, 03m, 58s"
"2022-10-12","108   ","08:27","17:27","09h, 00m, 57s"
"2022-10-14","108   ","09:02","23:20","14h, 18m, 30s"
"2022-10-15","108   ","10:02","10:12","00h, 10m, 25s"
"2022-10-18","108   ","07:48","07:50","00h, 02m, 26s"
"2022-10-19","108   ","08:14","14:51","06h, 36m, 18s"
"2022-10-03","109   ","08:36","19:23","10h, 47m, 19s"
"2022-10-04","109   ","08:23","17:25","09h, 02m, 17s"
"2022-10-05","109   ","08:37","19:52","11h, 14m, 45s"
"2022-10-06","109   ","08:30","20:54","12h, 23m, 42s"
"2022-10-07","109   ","08:32","19:08","10h, 35m, 35s"
"2022-10-10","109   ","08:27","17:23","08h, 56m, 57s"
"2022-10-11","109   ","08:29","16:12","07h, 43m, 12s"
"2022-10-12","109   ","08:32","20:08","11h, 35m, 31s"
"2022-10-13","109   ","08:32","17:33","09h, 01m, 31s"
"2022-10-14","109   ","08:49","19:01","10h, 11m, 49s"
"2022-10-17","109   ","08:33","18:34","10h, 01m, 13s"
"2022-10-18","109   ","08:34","17:54","09h, 20m, 01s"
"2022-10-19","109   ","08:27","08:29","00h, 02m, 08s"
"2022-10-03","112   ","08:04","17:40","09h, 35m, 49s"
"2022-10-04","112   ","09:06","16:26","07h, 19m, 34s"
"2022-10-05","112   ","08:09","17:24","09h, 15m, 06s"
"2022-10-06","112   ","08:02","18:32","10h, 30m, 01s"
"2022-10-07","112   ","08:07","18:40","10h, 32m, 47s"
"2022-10-10","112   ","08:02","18:05","10h, 03m, 03s"
"2022-10-11","112   ","08:05","18:05","10h, 00m, 03s"
"2022-10-12","112   ","08:03","18:04","10h, 01m, 13s"
"2022-10-13","112   ","08:06","18:27","10h, 21m, 10s"
"2022-10-14","112   ","08:23","18:19","09h, 56m, 07s"
```

I want output is like this:

```
"Day","Person","Start","End","Elapsed"
"2022-10-01","108   ","22:34","22:35","00h, 01m, 25s"
"2022-10-04","108   ","08:44","08:46","00h, 02m, 01s"
"2022-10-10","108   ","14:13","18:19","04h, 06m, 52s"
"2022-10-11","108   ","09:38","09:42","00h, 03m, 58s"
"2022-10-12","108   ","08:27","17:27","09h, 00m, 57s"
"2022-10-14","108   ","09:02","23:20","14h, 18m, 30s"
"2022-10-15","108   ","10:02","10:12","00h, 10m, 25s"
"2022-10-18","108   ","07:48","07:50","00h, 02m, 26s"
"2022-10-19","108   ","08:14","14:51","06h, 36m, 18s"
Employee total working hrs with minutes in all days = ?
"2022-10-03","109   ","08:36","19:23","10h, 47m, 19s"
"2022-10-04","109   ","08:23","17:25","09h, 02m, 17s"
"2022-10-05","109   ","08:37","19:52","11h, 14m, 45s"
"2022-10-06","109   ","08:30","20:54","12h, 23m, 42s"
"2022-10-07","109   ","08:32","19:08","10h, 35m, 35s"
"2022-10-10","109   ","08:27","17:23","08h, 56m, 57s"
"2022-10-11","109   ","08:29","16:12","07h, 43m, 12s"
"2022-10-12","109   ","08:32","20:08","11h, 35m, 31s"
"2022-10-13","109   ","08:32","17:33","09h, 01m, 31s"
"2022-10-14","109   ","08:49","19:01","10h, 11m, 49s"
"2022-10-17","109   ","08:33","18:34","10h, 01m, 13s"
"2022-10-18","109   ","08:34","17:54","09h, 20m, 01s"
"2022-10-19","109   ","08:27","08:29","00h, 02m, 08s"
Employee total working hrs with minutes in all days = ?
"2022-10-03","112   ","08:04","17:40","09h, 35m, 49s"
"2022-10-04","112   ","09:06","16:26","07h, 19m, 34s"
"2022-10-05","112   ","08:09","17:24","09h, 15m, 06s"
"2022-10-06","112   ","08:02","18:32","10h, 30m, 01s"
"2022-10-07","112   ","08:07","18:40","10h, 32m, 47s"
"2022-10-10","112   ","08:02","18:05","10h, 03m, 03s"
"2022-10-11","112   ","08:05","18:05","10h, 00m, 03s"
"2022-10-12","112   ","08:03","18:04","10h, 01m, 13s"
"2022-10-13","112   ","08:06","18:27","10h, 21m, 10s"
"2022-10-14","112   ","08:23","18:19","09h, 56m, 07s"
Employee total working hrs with minutes in all days = ?
```

i am using this powershell code to sort in ascending order

`
import-csv "c:\temp\export.csv" -Delimiter ","| Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = "person"}, @{Expression = "Date"} | export-csv "c:\temp\export2.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," -Force

`

Comment: Start by using [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv#:~:text=The%20Import%2DCsv%20cmdlet%20creates,by%20the%20Export%2DCsv%20cmdlet.) instead of Get-Content so you have custiom objects with properties you can use for the calculations. But why not have a spreadsheet do the work?

Comment: @KeithMiller thanks for replying, i am new in coding i have no idea how to use custom objects properties for calculations.  can you please share an example please. i will be very thankful to you

Comment: The sample data you shared seem to be invalid CSV data. There's no delimiter and there is an empty row between each data row. Could you share the original format without any formatting formatted as code, please?

Comment: @Olaf please now my csv data as there is same output i have updated in my question

Answer (score 1):

As I already mentioned before - you cannot have the CSV the way you posted as this would be an invalid CSV format. Try the following snippet:

```
$InputData = @'
"Day","Person","Start","End","Elapsed"
"2022-10-01","108   ","22:34","22:35","00h, 01m, 25s"
"2022-10-04","108   ","08:44","08:46","00h, 02m, 01s"
"2022-10-10","108   ","14:13","18:19","04h, 06m, 52s"
"2022-10-11","108   ","09:38","09:42","00h, 03m, 58s"
"2022-10-12","108   ","08:27","17:27","09h, 00m, 57s"
"2022-10-14","108   ","09:02","23:20","14h, 18m, 30s"
"2022-10-15","108   ","10:02","10:12","00h, 10m, 25s"
"2022-10-18","108   ","07:48","07:50","00h, 02m, 26s"
"2022-10-19","108   ","08:14","14:51","06h, 36m, 18s"
"2022-10-03","109   ","08:36","19:23","10h, 47m, 19s"
"2022-10-04","109   ","08:23","17:25","09h, 02m, 17s"
"2022-10-05","109   ","08:37","19:52","11h, 14m, 45s"
"2022-10-06","109   ","08:30","20:54","12h, 23m, 42s"
"2022-10-07","109   ","08:32","19:08","10h, 35m, 35s"
"2022-10-10","109   ","08:27","17:23","08h, 56m, 57s"
"2022-10-11","109   ","08:29","16:12","07h, 43m, 12s"
"2022-10-12","109   ","08:32","20:08","11h, 35m, 31s"
"2022-10-13","109   ","08:32","17:33","09h, 01m, 31s"
"2022-10-14","109   ","08:49","19:01","10h, 11m, 49s"
"2022-10-17","109   ","08:33","18:34","10h, 01m, 13s"
"2022-10-18","109   ","08:34","17:54","09h, 20m, 01s"
"2022-10-19","109   ","08:27","08:29","00h, 02m, 08s"
"2022-10-03","112   ","08:04","17:40","09h, 35m, 49s"
"2022-10-04","112   ","09:06","16:26","07h, 19m, 34s"
"2022-10-05","112   ","08:09","17:24","09h, 15m, 06s"
"2022-10-06","112   ","08:02","18:32","10h, 30m, 01s"
"2022-10-07","112   ","08:07","18:40","10h, 32m, 47s"
"2022-10-10","112   ","08:02","18:05","10h, 03m, 03s"
"2022-10-11","112   ","08:05","18:05","10h, 00m, 03s"
"2022-10-12","112   ","08:03","18:04","10h, 01m, 13s"
"2022-10-13","112   ","08:06","18:27","10h, 21m, 10s"
"2022-10-14","112   ","08:23","18:19","09h, 56m, 07s"
'@ | 
ConvertFrom-Csv



$Result = 
$InputData |
Select-Object -Property Person,
@{
    Name       = 'WorkingHours'
    Expression = {
        New-TimeSpan -Start $_.Start -End $_.End
    }
}

$Result | 
Group-Object -Property Person |
ForEach-Object {
    $sum = New-TimeSpan
    $_.Group.WorkingHours |
        ForEach-Object {
            $Sum += $_
        }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Employee = $_.Name
        Hours = [System.Math]::Floor($sum.TotalHours)
        Minutes = $Sum.Minutes
    }
}
```

The result would be this:

```
Employee Hours Minutes
-------- ----- -------
108         34      20
109        120      55
112         97      35
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it right.

```
"Day","Person","Start","End","Elapsed"
"2022-10-04","108   ","08:44","08:46","00h, 02m, 01s"
"2022-10-10","108   ","14:13","18:19","04h, 06m, 52s"
"2022-10-11","108   ","09:38","09:42","00h, 03m, 58s"
"2022-10-12","108   ","08:27","17:27","09h, 00m, 57s"
"2022-10-14","108   ","09:02","23:20","14h, 18m, 30s"
"2022-10-15","108   ","10:02","10:12","00h, 10m, 25s"
"2022-10-18","108   ","07:48","07:50","00h, 02m, 26s"
"2022-10-19","108   ","08:14","14:51","06h, 36m, 18s"
Employee total working hrs with minutes in all days = 34 hrs 21 mins 27 secs
"Day","Person","Start","End","Elapsed"
"2022-10-03","109   ","08:36","19:23","10h, 47m, 19s"
"2022-10-04","109   ","08:23","17:25","09h, 02m, 17s"
"2022-10-05","109   ","08:37","19:52","11h, 14m, 45s"
"2022-10-06","109   ","08:30","20:54","12h, 23m, 42s"
"2022-10-07","109   ","08:32","19:08","10h, 35m, 35s"
"2022-10-10","109   ","08:27","17:23","08h, 56m, 57s"
"2022-10-11","109   ","08:29","16:12","07h, 43m, 12s"
"2022-10-12","109   ","08:32","20:08","11h, 35m, 31s"
"2022-10-13","109   ","08:32","17:33","09h, 01m, 31s"
"2022-10-14","109   ","08:49","19:01","10h, 11m, 49s"
"2022-10-17","109   ","08:33","18:34","10h, 01m, 13s"
"2022-10-18","109   ","08:34","17:54","09h, 20m, 01s"
"2022-10-19","109   ","08:27","08:29","00h, 02m, 08s"
Employee total working hrs with minutes in all days = 120 hrs 56 mins 00 secs
"Day","Person","Start","End","Elapsed"
"2022-10-03","112   ","08:04","17:40","09h, 35m, 49s"
"2022-10-04","112   ","09:06","16:26","07h, 19m, 34s"
"2022-10-05","112   ","08:09","17:24","09h, 15m, 06s"
"2022-10-06","112   ","08:02","18:32","10h, 30m, 01s"
"2022-10-07","112   ","08:07","18:40","10h, 32m, 47s"
"2022-10-10","112   ","08:02","18:05","10h, 03m, 03s"
"2022-10-11","112   ","08:05","18:05","10h, 00m, 03s"
"2022-10-12","112   ","08:03","18:04","10h, 01m, 13s"
"2022-10-13","112   ","08:06","18:27","10h, 21m, 10s"
"2022-10-14","112   ","08:23","18:19","09h, 56m, 07s"
Employee total working hrs with minutes in all days = 97 hrs 34 mins 53 secs
```

Here is the code

```
$input_filename = "c:\temp\test.txt"
$output_filename = "c:\temp\test1.txt"

#$match = Select-String -Path "c:\temp\test.txt" -Pattern '^(?<date>\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d)\s+(?<person>[^\s]+)\s+(?<start>[^\s]+)\s+(?<end>[^\s]+)\s+(?<elapsed>.*$)'
$match = Select-String -Path $input_filename -Pattern '^"(?<date>\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)","(?<person>[^\s]+)\s+","(?<start>[^"]+)","(?<end>[^"]+)","(?<elapsed>[^"]+)'
#Write-Host $match

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$i = 0
foreach( $row in $match.Matches )
{
   if(++$i -gt 1)
   {
      $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
      $j = 0
      foreach($group in $row.Groups)
      {
          if(++$j -gt 1)
          {
             $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $group.Name -NotePropertyValue $group.Value
          }
      }
      $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
   }
}

$table = $table | Sort-Object {$_.person},{[System.DateTime]::ParseExact($_.date, "yyyy-MM-dd", $null)}

$table | format-table

$groups = $table | Group-Object {$_.person}
#$groups | Format-Table

$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($output_filename)

$pattern = "^(?<hours>\d{2})h,\s(?<minutes>\d{2})m, (?<seconds>\d{2})s" 
foreach($group in $groups)
{
   $writer.WriteLine("""Day"",""Person"",""Start"",""End"",""Elapsed""")
   $timeSpan = New-TimeSpan
   $hours = 0
   foreach($col in $group.Group)
   {
       $writer.WriteLine("""" + [System.String]::Join(""",""", @($col.date, $col.person.PadRight(6), $col.start, $col.end, $col.elapsed)) + """")
       $match = $col.elapsed | Select-String -Pattern $pattern
       $hours = [int]$match.Matches.groups[1].value  #.hours.Value
       $minutes = [int]$match.Matches.groups[2].value
       $seconds = [int]$match.Matches.groups[3].value
       $newTimeSpan = New-TimeSpan -Hours $hours -Minutes $minutes -Seconds $seconds
       $timeSpan += $newTimespan
   }
    $totalHours =("{0:00} hrs {1:00} mins {2:00} secs" -f (24 * $timeSpan.Days + $timeSpan.Hours),$timeSpan.Minutes, $timeSpan.Seconds)
    $writer.WriteLine("Employee total working hrs with minutes in all days = {0}", $totalHours)
    $last = $group.Group | Select-Object -Last 1
    $last.elapsed = $last.elapsed + ", " + $totalHours
}
$table | format-table
$writer.Flush()
$writer.Close()
```

Comment: Why would TimeSpan not work? The input start time and end time do not have seconds as well?!

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your reply can you please make me understand what kind of results you are saying that has achieved from your code please explain, what is the content inside of test.txt file.

Comment: The text is exactly what you posted in your csv file.

Comment: @Olaf : The start and end times do not have seconds.  Only the elapsed column has seconds.  The elapse time is the end column - start but more precise.

Comment: @jdweng i used ur code with my given csv data but there is no out put received !!

Comment: @jdweng - sajjad muslim mentioned he wanted to calculate the working hours. Do seconds really matter for this purpose?? ;-)  ... For most of the cases for such a purpose we round up the time to full 15 minutes anyway.   `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @sajjadmuslim Did you try my code suggestion as well?

Comment: @Olaf yes i tried and got results on powershell screen, when i put | for export csv i got unusual out put, Secondly one of my requirement has changed, now i need all employee working hrs to be calculate from my csv file data instead of person 'sajjad'. if you can help me in this it will worth for me how ever your help has worked alot for me i must say you are a code master amazing knowledge you have thanks

Comment: My code was using you original posted csv.  I had to change first line of code to work with new format.  I left the original line of code commented so you can see the difference.  My code display result to console.  I didn't save to a file because original input was not truly csv.

Comment: @sajjadmuslim A timespan is a complex type. What output would you like to see in the CSV file? If you change the requirement you have to specify it. :-/ Please update your question.

Comment: @Olaf question updated please see if you can do any thing thanks again for your support

Comment: I updated code to give desired output in a file.